# Visualizing $(\cos(x+y),x)$ or similar?

Tags: vector-fields

Visualizing $(\cos(x+y),x)$ or similar?

Seems a bit complicated.

$\cos(x)$ is the usual, but I don't understand how it behaves in this kind of situation.

Comment: WolframAlpha can do this, FWIW: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+vector+field+%28cos%28x+%2B+y%29%2C+x%29

Comment: @Qiaochu Yes, but I'm interested in if it's possible to "predict" without computing what the graph is about to look like.

Comment: Indeed! Where is $x+y$ constant? Compare with the WolframAlpha plot ;)

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+cos%28x%2By%29